# Migrate tags from Photoshop Elements to Picasa

Tags: migration, picasa, tags

How do I migrate my hundreds of beloved tags from Photoshop Elements to Picasa?

**UPDATE:**
I wish to preserve the tag hierarchy, stars points and captions.

Answer (score 1):

If you do what is suggested in [Do Tags Added in Photoshop Elements Carry Over to Other Software?](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/pselements/f/preservetags.htm) to make sure the tag info is written into all your files' metadata, then, from other things I've read, Picasa should be able to recognize them.

Have you tried doing this and are having a problem?

Comment: AFAIK that does not keep the tag hierarchy that exists in Photoshop Elements, but rather flattens the tags. This is problematic in particular when you have different tags with the same name located in various locations in the tag hierarchy.

Comment: Does Picasa support hierarchical tags?

Answer (score 1):

Picasa 3 does not support hierarchical tags or the starred rating system. However, if you just want to migrate the flattened tags (you could always rename duplicate named nested tags), just select all images in Elements, then in the file menu, there's a "write tags to file" option.

I too like the hierarchical tags feature of Elements.  On the other hand, Elements crashes and burns when I try to add any photos taken with my Galaxy Note 2, so we're pretty much stuck between a rock and a hard place.